# Setting-up SSH-tunnel for VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn

I have a laptop running Ubuntu.  I also rent a VPS running Ubuntu.  I've bought a paid VPN-service, which I use on my laptop.

I was wondering how I can set-up a SSH-tunnel or something similar, from my laptop to the VPS I'm renting, so I then can run VPN (from my laptop) "through" it (to the VPS), to the VPN-server.  The reason I wish to do so, is that a place I often work blocks my VPN-service, but not my SSHing to my VPS...

While I have been using Linux for a while, I'm a novice when it comes to setting-up virtual network-devices, advanced routing, and so on... so *please* spoonfeed me (using small words and colorful pictures ;-)

I have been googling and looking at various answers on the StackExchange-network, but not seems to be exactly what I'm after.  SSH-tunneling seemed promising, but since I don't have/know an exact domain and port for my VPN, I couldn't figure out how to use it...  I guess I may need to set-up some virtual network-device on my laptop (which ends on the VPS), and connect VPN through it - but how to do this, sadly goes over my head.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest why to tunnel all traffic through SSH similar to a VPN is to use the [`sshuttle` package](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle).

First, install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install sshuttle
```

Then connect to the SSH tunnel and redirect your default route to go through it:

```
sshuttle  -vv --dns -r username@sshserver[:port] 0.0.0.0/0
```

This will forward **all** TCP traffic through your SSH connection, including DNS requests. If you still want DNS handled locally, you can remove the `--dns` flag.

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm, thanks! For macOS, use `brew install sshuttle` instead of  `sudo apt-get install sshuttle`.

Comment: This works great! Thanks a lot!  Regarding the port, how can I find which port(s) I should use ?  For the moment I left the option out, so I guess I am forwarding to all ports?

Answer (score 6):

#### Create a tunnel

```
ssh -fND 7001 yourVPN
```

#### Open Chromium to use Proxy

```
chromium-browser --proxy-server=socks5://localhost:7001
```

#### Notes

- **7001** is the port and can be changed, so long that they both match
- You can also pass `--user-data-dir=/tmp/someDir` to `chromium` to use a different instance of Chromium

Comment: It seems that the separate `--user-data-dir` is required, otherwise an existing Chromium instance is used, which doesn't use the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

can i propose an easy solution just dont vote me down im a total novice

why cant you connect to the vpn service you brought from the vps ?, setup a openvpn server on the vps and connect to your vps's openvpn server from your client computer. Trust me it works i just confirmed using my virtual machines and an public vpn server.

```
root@eminem:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:58:c1:62  
          inet addr:172.16.32.5  Bcast:172.16.32.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe58:c162/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9484 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8638 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3820414 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:3520084 (3.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:161882 (161.8 KB)  TX bytes:161882 (161.8 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3052 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:635287 (635.2 KB)  TX bytes:2218229 (2.2 MB)

root@eminem:~# openvpn --config /home/eminem/oki.ovpn
```

connecting to an external vpnserver in your case your vpn service from your vps server

```
root@eminem:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:58:c1:62  
          inet addr:172.16.32.5  Bcast:172.16.32.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe58:c162/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9763 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3851001 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:3551440 (3.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:578 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:578 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:162965 (162.9 KB)  TX bytes:162965 (162.9 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3052 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:635287 (635.2 KB)  TX bytes:2218229 (2.2 MB)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.211.1.21  P-t-P:10.211.1.22  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

root@eminem:~# iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
```

simple iptables rule to masqarade all traffic from its tun0 interface to external vpn server's tun1 interface so we can go out to the internet using vpn tunnel of that external vpn server,when we connect to vps server's openvpn server and get a ip from the tun0 adapter

now finally connect to your vps server's openvpn server

```
shady@shady:~$ sudo openvpn --config Desktop/client.ovpn
```

Volla ! browse the internet without worrying about your vpn-service blockage

[image]

Comment: Most VPS solutions don't allow the installation of VPN services for "security reasons".

Comment: sorry i didn't knew

Comment: It's okay. I'm not down voting you, because you have a (mostly) valid answer. I was just providing one reason why this may not have been done. While most VPS solutions block this, one of the most popular cloud hosts (Amazon) does not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution after you have connected a client machine to an OpenVPN server:

For SSH through the VPN tunnel: [Connected to OpenVPN Server but can't SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069846/connected-to-openvpn-server-but-cant-ssh)

On the Openvpn host:

$ sudo ufw enable
$ sudo ufw allow 1194/udp comment "Allowing OpenVPN Connections"
$ sudo ufw allow from 10.8.0.1/24 to any port 22 proto tcp comment "SSH allowed for VPN clients"

On the client side:

Make sure OpenSSH is installed and running and port 22 is open on the firewall.