# openvpn and ssh don't work

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I have configured the ssh server for remote connection and it works perfectly.

I run a docker container for the openvpn service using the image **"kylemanna / openvpn"**, so far so good.

If I try to connect to the ssh it works without problems, if I connect to the vpn too, it works fine, but if I am connected to the vpn and try to connect by ssh to the same server it gives me a timeout. To connect via ssh I have set the real ip and I have also tested with the ip of the vpn tunnel and in no case is it connected.

I read [connected-to-openvpn-server-but-cant-ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069846/connected-to-openvpn-server-but-cant-ssh) but not works for me.

**EDIT**

When type **ufw status** see:

```
    To                      Action      From
1194/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere    #Allowing OpenVPN
22/tcp                      ALLOW       Anywhere    # SSH allowed
```

Even if I stop the ufw service with "**sudo systemctl stop ufw.service**" I cannot connect via **ssh** if I am connected to the **vpn**

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the firewall with

> ufw disable

This command

> sudo systemctl stop ufw.service

Just disables de service and the rules maybe still working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but my goal is not to disable the firewall but to be able to access through it